# what does fork/exec : permission denied mean?

Tags: kubernetes, container, gitlab

I am building a container inside of a container(Gitlab runner kubernetes pod) but it keeps failing. The Dockerfile of the container to build is:

```
FROM ubuntu 
USER root
RUN ["touch", "hello"]
RUN touch test
CMD ["echo", "hello"]
```

it fails in the line `RUN ["touch", "hello"]` with:

```
process exited with error: fork/exec /usr/bin/touch: permission deniedsubprocess exited with status 1
```

When I comment that line out it fails in the next one with:

```
process exited with error: fork/exec /bin/sh: permission deniedsubprocess exited with status 1
```

The user is root so there should be no permission errors and since im building `FROM ubuntu` the exec flags for `/bin` are set.

I have tried building this Dockerfile outside of the gitlab runner pod.
I started a new pod with `kubectl run ...` and ran `buildah bud .`
inside of it and it worked.
So what does the error message mean?